# How do I append an element created as a result of a function?

Tags: javascript

I've created a function (create_entry) which builds and styles a div box (entry) that I'm wanting to later append to second div (entries) by calling another function (append_entry).

```
const create_entry = () => {

  // Element Creation
  let entry_div = document.createElement('div'); // Entry
  let entry_div_date = document.createElement('span'); // Date
  let entry_div_content = document.createElement('p'); // Content
  let entry_div_button = document.createElement('button'); // Button

  // Element Styling
  entry_div.className = 'entry';
  entry_div_date.className = 'date';
  entry_div_button.className = 'remove';
  entry_div_button.style.marginTop = '10px';

  // Element Populating
  entry_div_content.textContent = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus, ullam.'

  // Element Appending
  entry_div.appendChild(entry_div_date);
  entry_div.appendChild(entry_div_content);
  entry_div.appendChild(entry_div_button);

  // Test Output
  console.log(entry_div);

  return entry_div;

}
```

Here is the second function, selecting the entries div and trying to append the element created in the first function to it.

```
const append_entry = (entry) => {
  let entries_div = document.querySelector('.entries');
  entries_div.appendChild(entry());
}
```

Called like so

```
append_entry(create_entry);
```

I wrongly assumed the first function would output the elements created, but instead outputs null.

How would I output the elements / node of the first function as an argument for the second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `return entry_div` at the bottom of `create_entry` function to return the element to be appended.

You are not executing the function you are passing. Execute the passed function by specifying the parenthesis at the end of the function name:

```
const append_entry = (entry) => {
  let entries_div = document.querySelector('.entries');
  var el = entry();
  entries_div.appendChild(entry());
}
```

**Working Code Example:**

```js
const create_entry = () => {

  // Element Creation
  let entry_div = document.createElement('div'); // Entry
  let entry_div_date = document.createElement('span'); // Date
  let entry_div_content = document.createElement('p'); // Content
  let entry_div_button = document.createElement('button'); // Button
  
  entry_div_button.innerHTML = 'My Button';

  // Element Styling
  entry_div.className = 'entry';
  entry_div_date.className = 'date';
  entry_div_button.className = 'remove';
  entry_div_button.style.marginTop = '10px';

  // Element Populating
  entry_div_content.textContent = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus, ullam.'

  // Element Appending
  entry_div.appendChild(entry_div_date);
  entry_div.appendChild(entry_div_content);
  entry_div.appendChild(entry_div_button);

  // Test Output
  console.log(entry_div);

  return entry_div;

}


const append_entry = (entry) => {
  let entries_div = document.querySelector('.entries');
  var el = entry();
  entries_div.appendChild(el);
}
append_entry(create_entry);
```

```html
<div class="entries"></div>
```

Comment: I tried this before to no avail. If I add return entry_div; and then console.log(create_entry) it returns the following ...

`() => {

  // Element Creation
  let entry_div = document.createElement('div'); // Entry
  let entry_div_date = document.createElement('span'); // Date
  let entry_div_content = document.createElemen…`

Comment: @jermainecraig, I have updated the answer...try now.

Comment: @jermainecraig, add `return entry_div` at the bottom of `create_entry` function....

Comment: Yeah that's in there. I'll update my code to reflect the current changes.

Comment: Although a console.log(entry()) inside the second function is outputting the elements correctly. Where a console.log(entry) is not. That's an improvement but the appendChild still reads entry() as null.

Comment: I actually had a bug on the html file preventing this from executing. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are forgot return statement after console.log(entry_div)
So your code should be

```
console.log(entry_div);
return entry_div;
```

Comment: I tried this before to no avail. If I add return entry_div; and then console.log(create_entry) it returns the following ...

`() => {

  // Element Creation
  let entry_div = document.createElement('div'); // Entry
  let entry_div_date = document.createElement('span'); // Date
  let entry_div_content = document.createElemen…`